# ElasticSearch Java Api: Update Existing Document

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-api

I am currently in the process of attempting to update an ElasticSearch document via the Java API. I have a groovy script with the following code:

```
static updateRequestById(String agencyIndex, String type, String id, def policy) {        
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest()
        updateRequest.docAsUpsert(true);
        updateRequest.parent("agentNumber");
        updateRequest.index(agencyIndex)
        updateRequest.type(type)
        updateRequest.id(id)
        updateRequest.doc("policies", policy)
        elasticsearchClient.update(updateRequest).get()
    }
```

The problem with I am having is that I want to update an array within the following document:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "successful": 10,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "int-b-agency",
            "_type": "jacket",
            "_id": "99808.1.27.09_4644",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "agentNumber": "99808.1.27.09",
               "fileNumber": "4644",
               "policies": [
                  {
                     "agentNumber": "99808.1.27.09",
                     "fileNumber": "4644",
                     "policyNumber": "2730609-91029084",
                     "checkNumber": "0",
                     "checkAmount": 0,
                     "createdOn": null,
                     "createdBy": "traxuser621",
                     "propertyTypeCode": "",
                     "propertyTypeDesc": "1-4 FAMILY RESIDENTIAL",
                     "ppaddress": "110 Allan Ct ",
                     "ppcity": "Jacksonville",
                     "ppstate": "FL",
                     "ppzip": "32226",
                     "ppcounty": "Duval",
                     "policytype": "",
                     "status": "Active",
                     "effectiveDate": "2015-04-01T00:00:00-05:00",
                     "formType": "BASIC OWNERS - ALTA Owners Policy 06_306_FL - FL Original Rate",
                     "rateCode": "FLOR",
                     "rateCodeDesc": "FL Original Rate",
                     "policyTypeCode": "1",
                     "policyTypeCodeDesc": "BASIC OWNERS",
                     "amount": 200000,
                     "hoiAgentNumber": "",
                     "proForma": false,
                     "pdfLocation": "\\\\10.212.61.206\\FNFCenter\\legacy_jacket_pdfs\\2015_4_FL6465\\Policy_2730609-91029084.pdf",
                     "legacyPolicy": "true",
                     "associatedPolNbr": null
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In the document above I have a document that has an array called "policies" with a single object. I want to be able to update the "policies" array with additional objects. The end result should look something like the following:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 10,
      "successful": 10,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "int-b-agency",
            "_type": "jacket",
            "_id": "41341.1.81.38_41340103",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "agentNumber": "41341.1.81.38",
               "fileNumber": "41340103",
               "policies": [
                  {
                     "agentNumber": "41341.1.81.38",
                     "fileNumber": "41340103",
                     "policyNumber": "8122638-91036874",
                     "checkNumber": "0",
                     "checkAmount": 0,
                     "createdOn": null,
                     "createdBy": "traxuser621",
                     "propertyTypeCode": "",
                     "propertyTypeDesc": "1-4 FAMILY RESIDENTIAL",
                     "ppaddress": "1800 Smith St ",
                     "ppcity": "sicklerville",
                     "ppstate": "PA",
                     "ppzip": "08105",
                     "ppcounty": "Dauphin",
                     "policytype": "",
                     "status": "Active",
                     "effectiveDate": "2016-02-01T00:00:00-06:00",
                     "formType": "TestData",
                     "rateCode": "PASALERATE",
                     "rateCodeDesc": "Sale Rate - Agent",
                     "policyTypeCode": "26",
                     "policyTypeCodeDesc": "SALE OWNERS",
                     "amount": 180000,
                     "hoiAgentNumber": "",
                     "proForma": false,
                     "pdfLocation": "SomeLocation1",
                     "legacyPolicy": "true",
                     "associatedPolNbr": null
                  },
                  {
                     "agentNumber": "41341.1.81.38",
                     "fileNumber": "41340103",
                     "policyNumber": "8122638-91036875",
                     "checkNumber": "0",
                     "checkAmount": 0,
                     "createdOn": null,
                     "createdBy": "traxuser621",
                     "propertyTypeCode": "",
                     "propertyTypeDesc": "1-4 FAMILY RESIDENTIAL",
                     "ppaddress": "1800 Smith St ",
                     "ppcity": "sicklerville",
                     "ppstate": "PA",
                     "ppzip": "08105",
                     "ppcounty": "Dauphin",
                     "policytype": "",
                     "status": "Active",
                     "effectiveDate": "2016-02-01T00:00:00-06:00",
                     "formType": "Test Data",
                     "rateCode": "PASALERATE",
                     "rateCodeDesc": "Sale Rate - Agent",
                     "policyTypeCode": "26",
                     "policyTypeCodeDesc": "SALE OWNERS",
                     "amount": 180000,
                     "hoiAgentNumber": "",
                     "proForma": false,
                     "pdfLocation": "SomeLocation2",
                     "legacyPolicy": "true",
                     "associatedPolNbr": null
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scripted update:

1. Put your new policy in a parameter, for example `policy`
2. Use a script like the following :

   ```
   if (!ctxt._source.policies) { ctxt._source.policies = [] }
   ctxt._source.policies += policy
   ```

See this documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have made the following modification  "static updateRequestById(String agencyIndex, String type, String id, def policy) {
 String script = "ctx._source.policies+=" + policy;
 UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(agencyIndex, type, id).routing("agentNumber").parent(id).script(script)
 elasticsearchClient.update(updateRequest).get()
}" and now I receive document missing exception. I have also attempting to do this directly within a curl call and received the same message. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Updates in inverted indexes are deletes and replacements of documents. There is no in-place update like you find in a db. ES uses Lucene under the hood which in-turn implements a kick-ass inverted index.